# How to remove everything after a word FOG in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, ultraedit

How can I remove everything starting from the Word FOG?

What I have:

```
JOB:EX ARGF2FOG73209
JOB:EX ARGF0FOG00000
JOB:EX ARGF4FOG15994
JOB:EX ARGF8FOG16460
JOB:EX ARGF18FOG18044
JOB:EX ARGF20FOG19461
JOB:EX ARGF26FOG20878
JOB:EX ARGF29FOG22294
JOB:EX ARGF32FOG23711
```

And what I want:

```
JOB:EX ARGF2
JOB:EX ARGF0
JOB:EX ARGF4
JOB:EX ARGF8
JOB:EX ARGF18
JOB:EX ARGF20
JOB:EX ARGF26
JOB:EX ARGF29
JOB:EX ARGF32
```

Comment: What have you tried? What did googling turn up? Why didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++ use search and replace in regular expression mode

Find: `FOG.*`

Replace with: (empty)

Search mode: Regular expression
don't check ". matches newline"

Comment: Thank you for your fast & correct answer. It solved my problem